# How to map enum to select dropdown in Storybook?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, storybook

I have a simple JS "enum" like this

```js
const MyEnum = {
  Aaa: 1,
  Bbb: 84,
};
```

And I have a simple story:

```js
import MyEnum from 'models/my-enum';
import HotSpot from 'hot-spot/hot-spot.vue';
import hotSpotProp from './hot-spot.stories.defaults';

export default {
  title: 'components/catalog/images/HotSpot',
  args: {
    hotspotProp: hotSpotProp,
    currentWidth: 360,
    selectedCallouts: [],
    calloutMode: true,
    originalWidth: 2100,
    title: 'Example tooltip',
  },
  argTypes: {
    oemId: {
      options: Object.keys(MyEnum), // an array of serializable values
      mapping: MyEnum, // maps serializable option values to complex arg values
      control: {
        type: 'select', // type 'select' is automatically inferred when 'options' is defined
        // labels: MyEnum,
      },
    },
  },
};

const Template = (args, { argTypes }) => ({
  components: { HotSpot },
  template: `<HotSpot v-bind="$props" />`,
  props: Object.keys(argTypes),
});

export const Default = Template.bind({});
```

[Example from docs](https://storybook.js.org/docs/vue/essentials/controls) is not working.

I have a `select` dropdown working, but it returns a `String` instead of a `Number` from mapping.

[image: Dropdown]

I get an error in my storybook in the console:

```
[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "oemId". Expected Number with value NaN, got String with value "Aaa".
```

How to map enum to select dropdown in Storybook?

Answer (score 24):

That storybook doc example is absolute horror.
Here's an example that will instantly show you what to do.

```
myValueList: {
      options: [0, 1, 2], // iterator
      mapping: [12, 13, 14], // values
      control: {
        type: 'select', 
        labels: ['twelve', 'thirteen', 'fourteen'],
      },
    }
```

Answer (score 13):

Enums end up as `Object`s, so:

```js
enum Nums {
 Zero,
 One,
 Two,
 Three,
}
```

Seems to become an `Object` that looks like:

```js
{
  0: "Zero",
  1: "One",
  2: "Two",
  3: "Three",
  One: 1,
  Three: 3,
  Two: 2,
  Zero: 0,
}
```

Since all object keys are strings or symbols in JavaScript, the only way I've been able to guarantee I only get the string values from an `Enum` is to use `Object.values` and filter strings:

```js
    oemId: {
      options: Object.values(MyEnum).filter(x => typeof x === "string"),
      mapping: MyEnum,
      control: {
        type: 'select',
      },
    },
```

Or, filter out the keys and retain an `Object` - this way Storybook can still default the value without issues:

```js
options: Object.entries(MyEnum)
    .filter(([, value]) => typeof value !== "string")
    .reduce((acc, [key, value]) => ({ ...acc, [key]: value }), {})
```

Comment: This is the best working answer so far, however it will give an `Invalid argType: 'type.options' should be an array.` in the console.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way without any helper for me was:

```
export default {
  title: 'One/SingleBarItem',
  component: SingleBarItem,
  //  Creates drowdown to select Phase enum values
  argTypes: {
    phase: {
      options: Object.values(NodeExecutionPhase),
      mapping: Object.values(NodeExecutionPhase),
      control: {
        type: 'select',
        labels: Object.keys(NodeExecutionPhase),
      },
    },
  },
} as ComponentMeta<typeof SingleBarItem>;
```

Where NodeExecutionPhase defined as:

```
enum Phase {
  UNDEFINED = 0,
  QUEUED = 1,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `Object.values` not the `.keys`.

```js
const MyEnum = {
    Aaa: 1,
    Bbb: 84,
};

Object.values(MyEnum); // -> [ 1, 84 ]
Object.keys(MyEnum);   // -> [ "Aaa", "Bbb" ]
```

Comment: Um... But how can I map string values to int values in the storybook?

Answer (score 1):

"Easy" (with this little helper):

```js
function enumOptions(someEnum) {
  return {
    options: Object.keys(someEnum)
      .filter((key) => !isNaN(parseInt(key)))
      .map((key) => parseInt(key)),
    mapping: someEnum,
    control: {
      type: 'select',
      labels: Object.values(someEnum).filter(
        (value) => typeof value === 'string'
      ),
    },
  }
}
```

This can the be used in the OP's example code as follows:

```js
export default {
  title: 'components/catalog/images/HotSpot',
  args: {
    oemId: MyEnum.MyValue  // default value for all stories can be used, 
                           // here "MyValue" will be preselected in dropdown
                           // (or individual `story.args` oemId value from MyEnum)
  },
  argTypes: {
    oemId: enumOptions(MyEnum)
  },
};
```

It is indeed surprising that this is not an out-of-the-box feature in storybook, requiring such a rather contrived workaround.

Thanks to [@Anthony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67467762#69390407)'s and [@Lee Chase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67467762#70924257)'s answers pointing in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I have given up on mapping for now and use a computed value, it pollutes the template a bit but a utility function or two can make it look a little tidier.

```
argTypes: {
    myValueList: {
        options: [0, 1, 2], // iterator
        control: {
            type: 'select', 
            labels: ['twelve', 'thirteen', 'fourteen'],
        },
    }
}
// .
// .
// .
const mappingMyValueList = [12, 13, 14];
// .
// .
// .
computed() {
    computedMyValueList() { 
      return () => mappingMyValueList[this.$props.myValueList];
    }
}
// .
// .
// .
<div>{{computedMyValueList}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Storybook v7.6.4 and this way works well.

```
// icon.enum.ts
enum IconNameEnum {
  Cash = 'cash',
  Edit = 'edit',
}

// icon.stories.ts
const meta: Meta<IconComponent> = {
  title: 'Shared/icons',
  component: IconComponent,
  argTypes: {
    name: {
      options: IconNameEnum,
      control: {
        type: 'select',
      },
    },
  },
};
```

The result is:
[image]