# How can you set custom labels for controls in Storybook?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, storybook

I'm trying to set custom labels for my controls in Storybook as outlined in the instructions [here,](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/essentials/controls) but it's not working as expected. According to the instructions  you can specify control.labels to configure custom labels for your checkbox, radio, or select input.

Right now I have a prop of size that allows the user to select the size of the component, but in Storybook it's showing the number value as opposed to name.  e.g.

[image]

Instead of the number values I want the labels to read the names from the enum below.

```
export enum sizes  {
  small = 32,
  default = 50,
  large = 100,
};
```

How can I update Storybook to use the enum sizes name instead of the value?

// storybook

```
export default {
title: 'Components/Spinner',
component: Spinner,
controls: { expanded: true },
argTypes: {
    type: {
        options: ['primary', 'secondary', 'success', 'warning', 'danger', 'info', 'light'],
        control: { type: 'radio'},
    },
    size: {
        options: [sizes.default, sizes.small, sizes.large],
        control: {
            type: 'radio',
            labels: {
                Default: 'Default',
                Small: 'Small',
                Large: 'Large'
            },
        },
    }
}
} as Meta;
```

FYI: If I update options to the following:

```
 options: sizes,
```

I get both the name and the value and only the name works
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else comes across this issue I solved it by manually typing in the values. According to this [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67467762/how-to-map-enum-to-select-dropdown-in-storybook) post enums end up as object. So it was outputting both the key and values.

```
export default {
title: 'Components/Spinner',
component: Spinner,
controls: { expanded: true },
argTypes: {
    type: {
        options: ['primary', 'secondary', 'success', 'warning', 'danger', 'info', 'light'],
        control: { type: 'radio'},
    },
    size: {
        options: [32, 50, 100],
        control: {
            type: 'radio',
            labels: {
                32: 'small',
                50: 'default',
                100: 'large',
            },
        },
    }
}
} as Meta;
```